# printing a temperature from arduino in 24 hr format

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature, real-time-clock

I have made a project to keep the record of temperature and time but while printing the records the time is not shown in proper way as in 24 hr format.

what i get is this:

8/4/2015   15:57:09   24.9

8/4/2015   15:57:39   25.39

8/4/2015   15:58:09   25.39

8/4/2015   15:58:39   23.44

8/4/2015   15:59:09   24.9

8/4/2015   15:59:39   25.39

8/4/2015   10:00:09   24.9

8/4/2015   10:00:39   25.39

8/4/2015   10:01:09   25.39

8/4/2015   10:01:39   25.39

8/4/2015   10:02:09   25.39

8/4/2015   10:02:39   25.39

but i wanted it to be:

8/4/2015   15:59:09   24.9

8/4/2015   15:59:39   25.39

8/4/2015   16:00:09   24.9

8/4/2015   16:00:39   25.39

Is it the problem because of hexadecimal number and decimal number?

here is the code for arduino uno

```c
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include<SPI.h>

const int temperature = A0;
int refresh = 30000;
DS3231 Clock;
bool Century=false;
bool h12;
bool PM;
float atm_temp;
byte year, month, date, DoW, hour, minute, second;
void setup() 
{
  Wire.begin();                     // Start the I2C interface

        pinMode(temperature,INPUT);       // Pinsetup for temperature sensor
        //settime();                      // Set time in RTC {uploaded at beginning only once}
        Serial.begin(115200);             // Start the serial interface
        Clock.setClockMode(false);        // false for 24 hr and true for 12 hr
}

void loop() 
{


  timedisp();
  tempdisp();
  delay(refresh);
 }
void tempdisp()
{

      atm_temp = ((analogRead(temperature)/10240.0)*5000);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.println(atm_temp);
}
void timedisp()
{
        Clock.getTime(year, month, date, DoW, hour, minute, second);

        Serial.print(month, DEC);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print(date, DEC);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print("20");
        Serial.print(year, DEC);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(hour, DEC);
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.print(minute, DEC);
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.print(second, DEC);

}
 void settime()
 {
        Clock.setSecond(50);//Set the second 
        Clock.setMinute(16);//Set the minute 
        Clock.setHour(5);  //Set the hour 
        Clock.setDoW(3);    //Set the day of the week
        Clock.setDate(4);  //Set the date of the month
        Clock.setMonth(8);  //Set the month of the year
        Clock.setYear(15);  //Set the year (Last two digits of the year)
 }
```

Comment: it's printing exactly in the format you want it to... If it doesn't print the temperatures you expect, maybe check your sensor.

Comment: my concern is, it is not printing time after 15:59:00 (i.e.16:xx:xx) but it is printing 10:xx:xx upto 17:xx:xx after  that